# Increasing parameter value in recursive call not working and it stays the same

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to do some pratcice in sql recursion and I am facing an issue with increasing an int variable here is my code

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS  test_rec_g;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_rec_g(n INT)
RETURNS TABLE (id varchar)
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
BEGIN
        IF n < 500 then 
                RAISE NOTICE 'Value: %', n;
                RETURN QUERY  select (test_rec_g(n+498)).* from edges;
        END IF;

END
$$;
SELECT * FROM test_rec_g(0);
```

So I do expect the each time n is increased by 498 but all I see is the following
[image]

I expect this pattern: 0 498 996 1494 ...

Am I missing anything?
How can I properly increase my n in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks pretty simple.  It issues '0' based on the first call, then it issues one instance of '498' for each row in the table, of which there are apparently 8.  There is a further call with 996 for each of the number of rows squared, but this layer of calls doesn't do anything (neither raise notices nor return rows) because the IF is not met.

Your expectation doesn't make any sense.  Why would it do things the IF specifically precludes it from doing?  If you want to see evidence of the do-nothing calls happening, put the RAISE NOTICE outside the IF.

Comment: Oooops I was so much into the details of the code that I missed this fact sorry and thanks for the hint

Comment: in btw do you have any explanation for this line? RETURN QUERY  select (test_rec_g(n+1)).* from edges; I saw it used  in another tutorial and trying to understand it